# What is the meaning of the "catchup marker" in Chat?

Tags: support, chat

Occasionally, in chat, a dashed bar appears. It is called `catchup-marker` (as you can read in its CSS).

[image: catchup marker]

The [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#read) says:

> If you have chat open but we don't think you've seen new messages, the system adds a dotted line like this

My questions:

- When exactly does it appear? The FAQ says, "Anything below that should be new to you", but how is it implemented?
- Can I somehow force it to appear?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually: It'll appear above the last monologue (that's what we call the "bubbles" of one or more subsequent messages by a single user) at the moment that you unfocus the chat window. So that's also how you force it to appear: By clicking on another window/your desktop/etc.

The last three positions that such a marker was inserted will stay visible, with older ones being fainter:

[image: three different shades of the catchup marker]

Comment: your arrows need work...  :)

Comment: Don't you dare criticizing my freehand arrows! They're beautiful!

Comment: I said it with a smiley....