# Get rid of catchup-marker

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, design

```
.monologue.catchup-marker {
    padding-top: 3px;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-top-width: 2px;
}

.monologue.catchup-marker-1 {
    border-top-color: #a6a6a6;
}

.monologue.catchup-marker-2 {
    border-top-color: #c6c6c6;
}

.monologue.catchup-marker-3 {
    border-top-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

Why are they here? I don't even understand [how they get chosen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109253/237813) and can't find any pattern in their placement. They look ugly.

Can they be removed?

Comment: Here's a rudimentary [userscript fix](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4029-se-chat-catch-up-marker-remover) in the meantime. One issue: because of the way the separators are added, it will display the last-added separator, so you will see one at a time. However, I think that this behavior actually makes more sense as a solution for [the original description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109253/237813): why would you want to know *all* of the places you've removed your focus from chat? The only useful one is the last-added (the last time you moved to a different window/tab).

Comment: @AstroCB *"why would you want to know all of the places you've removed your focus from chat?"* - Only the most recent 3 stay visible.

Comment: @JasonC That's true: the same logic applies, though.

Comment: @JasonC Also, I don't necessarily agree here: I think the separators can be quite useful, and I don't think they should be removed, but I'm just giving the option.

Comment: Version 2.0.0 removes *all* of the separators (your intended purpose).

Answer (score 1):

If you refresh the page, they go away.

At any given time, [only the most recent 3 are visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109253/230261).

Personally, I find all three to be useful. It gives me some reference points in time, and more importantly, reduces the chance of a "false" marker (perhaps I switched to the chat tab again by mistake, or I'm just not ready to "catch up") overwriting the marker I really want to see.